# Show that contraction to $\mathbb Z$ of the prime ideal $\langle \sqrt 2 \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$ is the prime ideal of even integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Consider the mapping $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$. Show that contraction of the prime ideal $\langle \sqrt 2 \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$  is the prime ideal of even integers of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Any element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$  is of the form $a+b \sqrt 2,\ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Also  $ \langle \sqrt 2\rangle =\{\sqrt 2,2,  2\sqrt 2,2^2,2^2\sqrt 2, 2^3, \cdots \}$.

How to define $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$  so that $f^{-1}(\langle \sqrt 2 \rangle)=\langle 2 \rangle=\{ 2^r:\ r \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$ ???

If I define \begin{align} f(2^r) &=0+(\sqrt 2)^r, \ r \geq 2 \\ f(2) &=2  \end{align}

would it suffice ??

Comment: Note that $\langle \sqrt 2\rangle=\{(a+b\sqrt 2)\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in \Bbb Z\} .$

Comment: @ThomasShelby, why is so? Why not only $\langle \sqrt 2\rangle=\{ (\sqrt 2)^r \}$ ?

Comment: It's just the definition. The ideal generated by an element $m$ in a commutative ring $R $ is given by $\{rm\mid r\in R \}$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby,oh yes

Comment: The description $\langle \sqrt 2\rangle=\{(a+b\sqrt 2)\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in \Bbb Z\}$ contains the proof! What are the integers in this set? Answer: $\{2b\mid b\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z [\sqrt2] $ by $a\mapsto a $ for all $a\in \Bbb Z$. Now every even integer is in $\langle \sqrt 2\rangle$. So $f^{-1}(\langle \sqrt 2\rangle)$ is a proper ideal containing $\langle  2\rangle$. Since $\langle  2\rangle$ is a maximal ideal, $f^{-1}(\langle \sqrt 2\rangle)=\langle  2\rangle$.

Comment: Are you saying $f(a)=a,\ \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$  ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Then $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt 2]$. Then how we get pre-image of $\sqrt 2$ under the inverse of $f$ ??

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR There's no preimage. $f $ is not surjective. Also, note that $f^{-1}(\langle \sqrt 2\rangle)=\{x\in\Bbb Z\mid f (x)\in \langle \sqrt 2\rangle\}. $